# Need to increment a value - but keep the leading zeros across multiple entries in Multiple Files Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, variables, increment

This is my baby:

```
$path = "C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\FNB 1 Trans\File Creation\DDINP"
$list = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Include "*.xml"
$initialvar=  '000625514690'
$newvar = $null

foreach($item in $list)
{
 (Get-Content -Raw $item) -replace '(?<=/)000(?=\d)',(Get-Random -Minimum 111 -Maximum 999) |Set-Content -NoNewLine $item
}
```

This code works 100%, but I have a requirement that needs to change the `000625514690` to an incremental value so I'd like it to look like this `000625514690` --> `000000000001`, `000000000002` etc.

The scenario is that there is a file that has 50 0000 of this transaction I'd, and the in the Folder there is another file etc.

Please may I ask for help. I have tried my own flavor of code but it doesnt work and looks horrendous...

```
$path = "C:\Users\Dell\Downloads\FNB 1 Trans\File Creation\DDINP"
$list = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Include "*.xml"
$initialvar=  '000625514690'
$newvar = $null

$arr = @() 
    1..999999999 | ForEach-Object { $arr += $_.ToString("000000000")}
foreach($item in $list)
{
 (Get-Content -Raw $item) -replace '(?<=/)000625514690(?=\d)',('arr') |Set-Content -NoNewLine $item
}
```

This is an example of the XML with one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.003.001.03">
    <FIToFICstmrDrctDbt>
        <GrpHdr>
            <MsgId>021/DDINP/00210001/20210419/100001</MsgId>
        <CreDtTm>2021-04-19T04:14:04</CreDtTm>
            <Authstn>
                <Prtry>A7A8E0D499CD8055382AA924</Prtry>
            </Authstn>
                <NbOfTxs>1</NbOfTxs>
            <CtrlSum>404685763</CtrlSum>
                    <TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="ZAR">750.00</TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt>
                   <IntrBkSttlmDt>2021-04-20</IntrBkSttlmDt>
            <SttlmInf>
                <SttlmMtd>CLRG</SttlmMtd>
                    <ClrSys>
                    <Prtry>AC</Prtry>
                </ClrSys>
            </SttlmInf>
            <InstgAgt>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <ClrSysMmbId>
                        <MmbId>210001</MmbId>
                    </ClrSysMmbId>
                </FinInstnId>
            </InstgAgt>
            <InstdAgt>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <ClrSysMmbId>
                        <MmbId>210000</MmbId>
                    </ClrSysMmbId>
                </FinInstnId>
            </InstdAgt>
        </GrpHdr>
<DrctDbtTxInf>
            <PmtId>
                <EndToEndId>CE1CE1ad3cac</EndToEndId>
                <TxId>0001/2021-04-19/000265498</TxId>
            </PmtId>
            <PmtTpInf>
                <LclInstrm>
                    <Prtry>03</Prtry>
                </LclInstrm>
                <SeqTp>RCUR</SeqTp>
                <CtgyPurp>
                    <Prtry>0046</Prtry>
                </CtgyPurp>
            </PmtTpInf>
            <IntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="ZAR">750.00</IntrBkSttlmAmt>
            <ChrgBr>SLEV</ChrgBr>
            <ReqdColltnDt>2021-04-19</ReqdColltnDt>
            <DrctDbtTx>
                <MndtRltdInf>
                    <MndtId>0021000120210419100001</MndtId>
                </MndtRltdInf>
            </DrctDbtTx>
            <Cdtr>
                <Nm>CASHMAN HYPHEN GROUP</Nm>
                <CtctDtls>
                    <PhneNb>+27-(0)722282282</PhneNb>
                </CtctDtls>
            </Cdtr>
            <CdtrAcct>
                <Id>
                    <Othr>
                        <Id>21452954</Id>
                    </Othr>
                </Id>
            </CdtrAcct>
            <CdtrAgt>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <ClrSysMmbId>
                        <MmbId>051001</MmbId>
                    </ClrSysMmbId>
                </FinInstnId>
            </CdtrAgt>
            <Dbtr>
                <Nm>Warren Bates</Nm>
            </Dbtr>
            <DbtrAcct>
                <Id>
                    <Othr>
                        <Id>404610763</Id>
                    </Othr>
                </Id>
                <Tp>
                    <Prtry>CACC</Prtry>
                </Tp>
            </DbtrAcct>
            <DbtrAgt>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <ClrSysMmbId>
                        <MmbId>632005</MmbId>
                    </ClrSysMmbId>
                </FinInstnId>
            </DbtrAgt>
            <RmtInf>
                <Ustrd>OBIZCERFLACOLC337-4926961711177595059802</Ustrd>
            </RmtInf>
        </DrctDbtTxInf>
    </FIToFICstmrDrctDbt>
</Document>
```

and here is one that has 5

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pacs.003.001.03">
    <FIToFICstmrDrctDbt>
        <GrpHdr>
            <MsgId>021/DDINP/00210001/20210416/100001</MsgId>
        <CreDtTm>2021-04-16T10:01:54</CreDtTm>
            <Authstn>
                <Prtry>A7A8E0D499CD8055382AA924</Prtry>
            </Authstn>
                <NbOfTxs>5</NbOfTxs>
            <CtrlSum>305586841770</CtrlSum>
                    <TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="ZAR">3750.00</TtlIntrBkSttlmAmt>
                   <IntrBkSttlmDt>2021-04-17</IntrBkSttlmDt>
            <SttlmInf>
                <SttlmMtd>CLRG</SttlmMtd>
                    <ClrSys>
                    <Prtry>AC</Prtry>
                </ClrSys>
            </SttlmInf>
            <InstgAgt>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <ClrSysMmbId>
                        <MmbId>210001</MmbId>
                    </ClrSysMmbId>
                </FinInstnId>
            </InstgAgt>
            <InstdAgt>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <ClrSysMmbId>
                        <MmbId>210000</MmbId>
                    </ClrSysMmbId>
                </FinInstnId>
            </InstdAgt>
        </GrpHdr>
<DrctDbtTxInf>
            <PmtId>
                <EndToEndId>CE1CE1ad3cac</EndToEndId>
                <TxId>0001/2021-04-16/000728670</TxId>
            </PmtId>
            <PmtTpInf>
                <LclInstrm>
                    <Prtry>03</Prtry>
                </LclInstrm>
                <SeqTp>RCUR</SeqTp>
                <CtgyPurp>
                    <Prtry>0046</Prtry>
                </CtgyPurp>
            </PmtTpInf>
            <IntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="ZAR">750.00</IntrBkSttlmAmt>
            <ChrgBr>SLEV</ChrgBr>
            <ReqdColltnDt>2021-04-16</ReqdColltnDt>
            <DrctDbtTx>
                <MndtRltdInf>
                    <MndtId>0021000120210416100001</MndtId>
                </MndtRltdInf>
            </DrctDbtTx>
            <Cdtr>
                <Nm>CASHMAN HYPHEN GROUP</Nm>
                <CtctDtls>
                    <PhneNb>+27-(0)722282282</PhneNb>
                </CtctDtls>
            </Cdtr>
            <CdtrAcct>
                <Id>
                    <Othr>
                        <Id>21452954</Id>
                    </Othr>
                </Id>
            </CdtrAcct>
            <CdtrAgt>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <ClrSysMmbId>
                        <MmbId>051001</MmbId>
                    </ClrSysMmbId>
                </FinInstnId>
            </CdtrAgt>
            <Dbtr>
                <Nm>Warren Bates</Nm>
            </Dbtr>
            <DbtrAcct>
                <Id>
                    <Othr>
                        <Id>61117293354</Id>
                    </Othr>
                </Id>
                <Tp>
                    <Prtry>SVGS</Prtry>
                </Tp>
            </DbtrAcct>
            <DbtrAgt>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <ClrSysMmbId>
                        <MmbId>410600</MmbId>
                    </ClrSysMmbId>
                </FinInstnId>
            </DbtrAgt>
            <RmtInf>
                <Ustrd>OBIZCERFLACOLC337-4926961711177595059802</Ustrd>
            </RmtInf>
        </DrctDbtTxInf>
<DrctDbtTxInf>
            <PmtId>
                <EndToEndId>CE1CE1ad3cac</EndToEndId>
                <TxId>0001/2021-04-16/000876801</TxId>
            </PmtId>
            <PmtTpInf>
                <LclInstrm>
                    <Prtry>03</Prtry>
                </LclInstrm>
                <SeqTp>RCUR</SeqTp>
                <CtgyPurp>
                    <Prtry>0046</Prtry>
                </CtgyPurp>
            </PmtTpInf>
            <IntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="ZAR">750.00</IntrBkSttlmAmt>
            <ChrgBr>SLEV</ChrgBr>
            <ReqdColltnDt>2021-04-16</ReqdColltnDt>
            <DrctDbtTx>
                <MndtRltdInf>
                    <MndtId>0021000120210416100001</MndtId>
                </MndtRltdInf>
            </DrctDbtTx>
            <Cdtr>
                <Nm>CASHMAN HYPHEN GROUP</Nm>
                <CtctDtls>
                    <PhneNb>+27-(0)722282282</PhneNb>
                </CtctDtls>
            </Cdtr>
            <CdtrAcct>
                <Id>
                    <Othr>
                        <Id>21452954</Id>
                    </Othr>
                </Id>
            </CdtrAcct>
            <CdtrAgt>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <ClrSysMmbId>
                        <MmbId>051001</MmbId>
                    </ClrSysMmbId>
                </FinInstnId>
            </CdtrAgt>
            <Dbtr>
                <Nm>Warren Bates</Nm>
            </Dbtr>
            <DbtrAcct>
                <Id>
                    <Othr>
                        <Id>61117293354</Id>
                    </Othr>
                </Id>
                <Tp>
                    <Prtry>SVGS</Prtry>
                </Tp>
            </DbtrAcct>
            <DbtrAgt>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <ClrSysMmbId>
                        <MmbId>410600</MmbId>
                    </ClrSysMmbId>
                </FinInstnId>
            </DbtrAgt>
            <RmtInf>
                <Ustrd>OBIZCERFLACOLC337-4926961711177595059802</Ustrd>
            </RmtInf>
        </DrctDbtTxInf>
<DrctDbtTxInf>
            <PmtId>
                <EndToEndId>CE1CE1ad3cac</EndToEndId>
                <TxId>0001/2021-04-16/000606745</TxId>
            </PmtId>
            <PmtTpInf>
                <LclInstrm>
                    <Prtry>03</Prtry>
                </LclInstrm>
                <SeqTp>RCUR</SeqTp>
                <CtgyPurp>
                    <Prtry>0046</Prtry>
                </CtgyPurp>
            </PmtTpInf>
            <IntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="ZAR">750.00</IntrBkSttlmAmt>
            <ChrgBr>SLEV</ChrgBr>
            <ReqdColltnDt>2021-04-16</ReqdColltnDt>
            <DrctDbtTx>
                <MndtRltdInf>
                    <MndtId>0021000120210416100001</MndtId>
                </MndtRltdInf>
            </DrctDbtTx>
            <Cdtr>
                <Nm>CASHMAN HYPHEN GROUP</Nm>
                <CtctDtls>
                    <PhneNb>+27-(0)722282282</PhneNb>
                </CtctDtls>
            </Cdtr>
            <CdtrAcct>
                <Id>
                    <Othr>
                        <Id>21452954</Id>
                    </Othr>
                </Id>
            </CdtrAcct>
            <CdtrAgt>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <ClrSysMmbId>
                        <MmbId>051001</MmbId>
                    </ClrSysMmbId>
                </FinInstnId>
            </CdtrAgt>
            <Dbtr>
                <Nm>Warren Bates</Nm>
            </Dbtr>
            <DbtrAcct>
                <Id>
                    <Othr>
                        <Id>61117293354</Id>
                    </Othr>
                </Id>
                <Tp>
                    <Prtry>SVGS</Prtry>
                </Tp>
            </DbtrAcct>
            <DbtrAgt>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <ClrSysMmbId>
                        <MmbId>410600</MmbId>
                    </ClrSysMmbId>
                </FinInstnId>
            </DbtrAgt>
            <RmtInf>
                <Ustrd>OBIZCERFLACOLC337-4926961711177595059802</Ustrd>
            </RmtInf>
        </DrctDbtTxInf>
<DrctDbtTxInf>
            <PmtId>
                <EndToEndId>CE1CE1ad3cac</EndToEndId>
                <TxId>0001/2021-04-16/000951332</TxId>
            </PmtId>
            <PmtTpInf>
                <LclInstrm>
                    <Prtry>03</Prtry>
                </LclInstrm>
                <SeqTp>RCUR</SeqTp>
                <CtgyPurp>
                    <Prtry>0046</Prtry>
                </CtgyPurp>
            </PmtTpInf>
            <IntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="ZAR">750.00</IntrBkSttlmAmt>
            <ChrgBr>SLEV</ChrgBr>
            <ReqdColltnDt>2021-04-16</ReqdColltnDt>
            <DrctDbtTx>
                <MndtRltdInf>
                    <MndtId>0021000120210416100001</MndtId>
                </MndtRltdInf>
            </DrctDbtTx>
            <Cdtr>
                <Nm>CASHMAN HYPHEN GROUP</Nm>
                <CtctDtls>
                    <PhneNb>+27-(0)722282282</PhneNb>
                </CtctDtls>
            </Cdtr>
            <CdtrAcct>
                <Id>
                    <Othr>
                        <Id>21452954</Id>
                    </Othr>
                </Id>
            </CdtrAcct>
            <CdtrAgt>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <ClrSysMmbId>
                        <MmbId>051001</MmbId>
                    </ClrSysMmbId>
                </FinInstnId>
            </CdtrAgt>
            <Dbtr>
                <Nm>Warren Bates</Nm>
            </Dbtr>
            <DbtrAcct>
                <Id>
                    <Othr>
                        <Id>61117293354</Id>
                    </Othr>
                </Id>
                <Tp>
                    <Prtry>SVGS</Prtry>
                </Tp>
            </DbtrAcct>
            <DbtrAgt>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <ClrSysMmbId>
                        <MmbId>410600</MmbId>
                    </ClrSysMmbId>
                </FinInstnId>
            </DbtrAgt>
            <RmtInf>
                <Ustrd>OBIZCERFLACOLC337-4926961711177595059802</Ustrd>
            </RmtInf>
        </DrctDbtTxInf>
<DrctDbtTxInf>
            <PmtId>
                <EndToEndId>CE1CE1ad3cac</EndToEndId>
                <TxId>0001/2021-04-16/000629765</TxId>
            </PmtId>
            <PmtTpInf>
                <LclInstrm>
                    <Prtry>03</Prtry>
                </LclInstrm>
                <SeqTp>RCUR</SeqTp>
                <CtgyPurp>
                    <Prtry>0046</Prtry>
                </CtgyPurp>
            </PmtTpInf>
            <IntrBkSttlmAmt Ccy="ZAR">750.00</IntrBkSttlmAmt>
            <ChrgBr>SLEV</ChrgBr>
            <ReqdColltnDt>2021-04-16</ReqdColltnDt>
            <DrctDbtTx>
                <MndtRltdInf>
                    <MndtId>0021000120210416100001</MndtId>
                </MndtRltdInf>
            </DrctDbtTx>
            <Cdtr>
                <Nm>CASHMAN HYPHEN GROUP</Nm>
                <CtctDtls>
                    <PhneNb>+27-(0)722282282</PhneNb>
                </CtctDtls>
            </Cdtr>
            <CdtrAcct>
                <Id>
                    <Othr>
                        <Id>21452954</Id>
                    </Othr>
                </Id>
            </CdtrAcct>
            <CdtrAgt>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <ClrSysMmbId>
                        <MmbId>051001</MmbId>
                    </ClrSysMmbId>
                </FinInstnId>
            </CdtrAgt>
            <Dbtr>
                <Nm>Warren Bates</Nm>
            </Dbtr>
            <DbtrAcct>
                <Id>
                    <Othr>
                        <Id>61117293354</Id>
                    </Othr>
                </Id>
                <Tp>
                    <Prtry>SVGS</Prtry>
                </Tp>
            </DbtrAcct>
            <DbtrAgt>
                <FinInstnId>
                    <ClrSysMmbId>
                        <MmbId>410600</MmbId>
                    </ClrSysMmbId>
                </FinInstnId>
            </DbtrAgt>
            <RmtInf>
                <Ustrd>OBIZCERFLACOLC337-4926961711177595059802</Ustrd>
            </RmtInf>
        </DrctDbtTxInf>
    </FIToFICstmrDrctDbt>
</Document>
```

If possible how would I say the one txid is 1, and then in the next file (the 100) one say, 2,3,4,5,6? - them being in 2 different files but in the same folder...

Comment: Using `-replace` on XML files is dangerous.. Better show us some of the XML so we can see which element in it should be replaced by this incremental value. Also, itis not clear whether the new value shoud increment of each file or if there are multiple of these values in a single file..

Comment: Hi Theo, yes there are multiple instances in the file of that value, plus there are multiple files. I will amend the question